# What is the best way to add longpress event for FloatingActionsBar?

Tags: android, android-layout, floating-action-button

First, I know how to do it but don't know if it is the best solution. So for clicking the item inside the FABar we can override `onItemClick(int position)`, however it seems that FABar doesn't have the method `onItemLongPressed(int position)` or something like that I can use. In order to handle longpress, I have to add `setOnLongClickListener()` to each of the item inside the FABar. Wondering if there is any other better way to do it?

Comment: I'm using `setOnLongClickListener()` and it works. And yes, you're right, it might be confusing. So I would say you use the best available method.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to make the items your own custom class that calls `setOnLongClickListener()` as part of it's constructor and you could pass in any state needed to handle the long click in the constructor as well

Comment: That seems an overkill, don't think it's worth to get a class just for handling longpress.

Comment: Well if your items have custom UI, state management, long press, touch, click handlers etc.  It's better to wrap it in a class than to copy paste code.  it will also be more testable